# Firebase authentication email/password failed attempts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We just tried testing failed email/password auth flow with our Firebase instance and see a user can get locked when email/password auth fails 5 times but that is only for 15-20 seconds. The questions we had are:

(1) Is this information documented some place?

(2) Is this configurable?

(3) This doesn't seem to work using emulator, is that a valid assumption?